# Looking for free collection of different vCards (*.vcf)

Tags: contacts, addressbook, vcf-vcard, data-collection

I am currently working on a vCard parser. For the testing of the different edge cases of vCards (the standard allows a high variance) I need a collection of vCards from different sources. 
At the moment I am working with some vCards I created on my own and was wondering if there is a free collection of vCards (*.vcf) in the web which I can use for testing purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a LGPL vcard test suite for testing vCard parsers:

https://gitlab.com/pwithnall/vcard-test-suite/-/tree/master

It cover valid and invalid card and looks extensive.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.